# How to link a Skype number to a Google Voice number?

Tags: google-voice, skype-for-web

I'm trying to link my Skype number to my Google Voice number so I can make a call. But guess what? Whenever Google calls to confirm the number one of the two hangs up automatically when I answer. So what can I check in either service to get these linked?

Comment: Is Skype already forwarding to Google Voice? Sounds like they're stuck in some sort of forward loop causing this.